# mysql: SET NAMES utf8 on each connection?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I use the following statement on every PHP page to set the connection to Unicode:

```
mysql_query ('SET NAMES utf8');
```

Is there a way I can skip this? By setting something on the server? I have a VPS so I should be able to access anything.

I supposed the real question is: do I need to? Will it speed things up I skip this statement for every single HTML page that is delivered?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can modify mysql config(my.cnf)

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
default-character-set=utf8
```

Comment: Is the line under `[mysqld]` really necessary?

Comment: It IS not necessary (it IS pointless actually), because 'default-character-set' is used only for clients. And if your client is **mysql** then and only then the mentioned "default-character-set=utf8" comes to play. In all other cases you have to set 'SET NAMES x'. So, the option under **mysqld** section is meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

There's no harm and effectively zero performance impact by running that command whenever you start a new connection.

If you wish to change the server configuration, [here is the appropriate manual page on setting the connection character set defaults](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html).  You'll want to read the rest of the sections on defaults as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just include a config file in every page, that contains all things related to creating a db connection?

This line is nesseccary, because you can really mess up data encoding in the db (been there, done that :))